# converting json file to csv in Python returns nothing?

Tags: python, json, csv

Here we have a large json file with nested content in that. We want to convert it to csv file,so that it could use it for data modeling, however I feel as the code is missing something, which I am unable to spot. I am very new to python and need help.

Following is how the content in the file looks like:

```
[{
"address": " -, Gulbarga-585102", 
"college": "College (Architecture)", 
"courses": [
{
    "brief_details": "", 
    "college_name": "School of ArchitecturePoojya Doddappa Appa College of Engineering", 
    "course_branch": "B.Arch", 
    "course_duration": " 5-year", 
    "course_nature": " Full-Time", 
    "course_title": "", 
    "course_type": " B.Arch", 
    "no_of_seats": " 60", 
    "qualifications": "", 
    "selection_process": ""
}
], 
"email": " principal@pdaengg.com", 
"fax": "08472-255685", 
"name": "School Of Architecturepoojya Doddappa Appa College Of    Engineering", 
"phone": "08472-224262 Extn. 435, 220742", 
"recognition": " V.t.u. Belgaum", 
"website": ""
}]
```

And following is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import listdir
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import fnmatch
import shelve
import json
import csv

def write_csv(read_file_path):
    data = json.loads(open(read_file_path).read())
    file_colleges = csv.writer(open(r"/home/maitreyee/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/colleges.csv", "w", newline=""))
    list_colleges_headers = ['name', 'recognition','address','phone','fax','email','website']
    file_colleges.writerow(list_colleges_headers)
    list_courses.list_colleges_headers = ['course_title', 'course_type','course_duration','course_nature','qualifications','brief_details','selection_process', 'course_branch', 'no_of_seats']

    for d in data:
        file_colleges.writerow(
            [d['name'], d['college'], d['recognition'], d['address'], d['phone'], d['fax'], d['website']])
        file_course.writerow(list_courses_headers)
        for course in d['courses']:
            file_course.writerow(
                [
                 (course['course_title'] if course['course_title'] is not None or course['course_title'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_type'] if course['course_type'] is not None or course['course_type'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_duration'] if course['course_duration'] is not None or course['course_duration'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_nature'] if course['course_nature'] is not None or course['course_nature'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['qualifications'] if course['qualifications'] is not None or course['qualifications'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['brief_details'] if course['brief_details'] is not None or course['brief_details'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['selection_process'] if course['selection_process'] is not None or course['selection_process'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_branch'] if course['course_branch'] is not None or course['course_branch'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['no_of_seats'] if course['no_of_seats'] is not None or course['no_of_seats'] != '' else 'NA')])
        pass

#def write_file(file, colleges):
#   db = shelve.open(file)
#   for college in colleges:
#       db[college.name] = college
#   db.close()
read_file_path = r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/collegesdb1.json'
#colleges = read_colleges(r"/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com1/collegedb1.json")
#new_write_file(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com1/')
```

And the code is returning an empty file

Below is the code of @7stud.have just modified the files location.

```
import json
import csv

def write_csv(jsonfile, outfile):

    with open(jsonfile) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    college_dict = data[0]

    college_keys = list(college_dict.keys())
    college_keys.remove('courses')
    college_keys.remove('college')

    courses_dict = data[0]['courses'][0]
    courses_keys = list(courses_dict.keys())
    courses_keys.remove('brief_details')

    with open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        headers = college_keys + courses_keys
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)

        row = (
            [
                college_dict[key] if college_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in college_keys
            ] 
            + 
            [
                courses_dict[key] if courses_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in courses_keys
            ]
        )

        csv_writer.writerow(row)

jsonfile = '/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/collegesdb1.json'
outfile = '/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/collegesdb/collegesout.csv'

write_csv(jsonfile, outfile)
```

And below is the error

```
 maitreyee@Maitreyee:~/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com$ python json2csv4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json2csv4.py", line 41, in <module>
    write_csv(jsonfile, outfile)
  File "json2csv4.py", line 15, in write_csv
    courses_dict = data[0]['courses'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This was silly of me. Sorry for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you plan on calling your `write_csv()` function in your program?
2. If you do call `write_csv()`, you will get the error:

> NameError: name 'list_courses' is not defined

If you just do this:

```
import json
import csv

def write_csv(read_file_path):
    data = json.loads(open(read_file_path).read())
    file_colleges = csv.writer(open('out.txt', "w", newline=""))
    list_colleges_headers = ['name', 'recognition','address','phone','fax','email','website']
    file_colleges.writerow(list_colleges_headers)


infile = "json.txt"
write_csv(infile)
```

you'll see that the file does contain output:

```
$ cat out.txt
name,recognition,address,phone,fax,email,website
```

**Edit:**

If the column order in the csv file isn't important:

```
import json
import csv

def write_csv(jsonfile, outfile):

    with open(jsonfile) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    college_dict = data[0]

    college_keys = list(college_dict.keys())
    college_keys.remove('courses')
    college_keys.remove('college')

    courses_dict = data[0]['courses'][0]
    courses_keys = list(courses_dict.keys())
    courses_keys.remove('brief_details')

    with open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        headers = college_keys + courses_keys
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)

        row = (
            [
                college_dict[key] if college_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in college_keys
            ] 
            + 
            [
                courses_dict[key] if courses_dict[key] else 'NA'
                for key in courses_keys
            ]
        )

        csv_writer.writerow(row)

jsonfile = 'data.json'
outfile = 'out.csv'

write_csv(jsonfile, outfile)
```

Comment: i also need the nested values for courses above in separate columns. and yes you are right that after doing the write csv I am getting the error, so I am doing some modifications to include the course values as well. I am going to put up the modified code here. If you have any suggestions on how to include the nested list kindly let me know.

Comment: @MaitreyeeTewari, See bottom of my answer.

Comment: Now i am getting the error 'List index out of range'?

Comment: @MaitreyeeTewari, Post the code that is causing the error along with the exact error message(copy and paste) at the bottom of your answer.